# Update Liferay-faces-alloy

Tags: liferay

Good Morning.

A few days ago I received an email from the National Cybersecurity Institute of Spain indicating that there is a vulnerability in the Liferay Faces Alloy library, Servlet (non-Portlet) 3.0+ environment.

Investigating I have seen that the version of Liferay 6.2 CE GA5 contains an affected library:

### liferay-portal-src-6.2-ce-ga5-20151118111117117/liferay-portal-src-6.2-ce-ga5/portal-web/third-party/alloy-2.0.0.67.zip

Can someone tell me how I can update this portal's own library? I have found information on how to change the library of a portlet but these are not affected by this vulnerability.

Regards

Comment: Notice: https://www.incibe-cert.es/alerta-temprana/avisos-seguridad/vulnerabilidad-dos-liferay-0

Answer (score 0):

As the alert indicated, this vulnerability does not affect portlets.

However, you are looking at the AlloyUI zip not the Liferay Faces Alloy JAR. Liferay Faces Alloy would be installed inside a JSF WAR's **`WEB-INF/lib`** folder. You would likely need to update to Liferay Faces Alloy `2.0.2`,* rebuild, and redeploy each JSF WAR that relies on Liferay Faces Alloy to update.

* Liferay Faces Alloy `2.0.2` is compatible with Liferay 6.2. Liferay Faces Alloy `3.0.2` is compatible with Liferay 7.0+.